# How to make user control load once?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one user control,named as "SocialShareElements", which's purpose is to share the page content/image into FaceBook.
I utilized this user control in my Index page.

I called this user control in a "IF" condition, within Index.aspx.
The pseudo code is like:

```
<% 
   if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
  {
%>
   <div class="deal-detail-head tzsg-margin-bottom-med">
     <MyControl:SocialShareElements ID="SocialShareElements1" runat="server"/> 
   </div>
   <div class="clear-both"></div>
<%
  }
  else
 {
 %>
   <div class="deal-test bottom-small">
     <MyControl:SocialShareElements ID="SocialShareElements" runat="server"/> 
   </div>
<% 
 } 
%>
```

When I test the FBShare function in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, it showed failed becuase I loaded "SocialShareElements" twice, and this makes meta data of "SocialShareElements" double in Index.aspx.

My question is how to adjust the logic of utilizing "SocialShareElements" in Index.aspx, to make it only be loaded once.

Thank you.

Comment: that should only be loaded once. Does the FBShare function kick off another postback?

Comment: So you're checking if the Request is Secure and then loading the SocalShareElement Either way? the only difference being the div classes and the added <div class="clear-both"></div>?

Comment: To @ElliotRodriguez: No, I am sure that FBShare doesn't trigger any postback.  To John: actually there are many different elements between "if" and "else" sections, and I just ignored them when posting this questions. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this from code-behind.

Modify your div on your aspx page to be available from server side:

```
<div id="socialShare" runat="server">

</div>
```

In your code-behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        SocialShareElements shareElement = LoadControl("SocialShareElements.ascx") as SocialShareElements;

        socialDiv.Controls.Add(shareElement);
    }
 }
```